# ActivityMock for Fragment in test project

Tags: android, android-testing

I have `Activity` that contains few `Fragments`, now I would like to test one of this `Fragment` but I would like to separate test and test only core functionality of selected `Fragment` not bothering what is happening in main `Activity`.

My idea is to create a mock `Activity` which will just add `Fragment` in `onCreate()` method. Then I will make some tests. But I would not like to include mock `Activity` to my main project, I would rather include it to test project. So I did something like this:

1. I have created `MockActivity`:

   ```
   public final class ActivityMock extends Activity {
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           FragmentTransaction t = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
           MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
           t.add(f, "MY_FRAGMENT");
           t.commit();
       }
   }
   ```
2. I want to test it like this:

   ```
   public final class MyFragmentTest extends
   ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<ActivityMock> {

       public MyFragmentTest() {
           super(ActivityMock.class);
       }

       public void testSomething() {
           ActivityMock mActivity = getActivity();
           //do some assertions
       }
   }
   ```

The problem is that I I get error:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve activity for: Intent {
    act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000  
    cmp=com.example/.test.ActivityMock }
```

Ok next I tried to modify test project `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <activity android:name=".ActivityMock" />
```

But I got same error. I think that is because anyway during test run main project is searched for `ActivityMock`. So I tried to add

```
    <instrumentation
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:targetPackage="com.example.test" />
```

I don know if it is a good idea, but main thought is that test project will be able to test (instrument) itself. But now I get:

```
    junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Exception in constructor: testSomething    
    (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.test.ActivityMock
```

So I think that modified `AndroidManifest.xml` worked but still `ActivityMock` class is being searched in main project, though it is in test project.
I assume that `getActivity()` method always look for activity class in main project.

Does anybody tried to test `Fragment` this way and was able to create `Activity` mock?

Cheers

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: I am trying to find an answer too. However, I think the problem is that there is no view created for the mock activity so you can add the fragment.